# $S5$ proof of $\diamond \square p\to \square p$

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am trying to solve exercises from the book [Modal Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521527147) by  Patrick Blackburn, Maarten de Rijke and Yde Venema. I am having a problem to solve one of the exercises in the section 1.6, it is the last part of exercise is 1.6.3 in page 37. Please help me.

> **Exercise** :
>   Give an $S5$ proof of $\diamond \square p\to \square p$

For the convenience I am here stating all the axioms of $S5$ system.

(PC axiom 1) $p\to (q\to p)$

(PC axiom 2) $(p\to (q\to r)) \to ((p\to q)\to (p\to r))$

(PC axiom 3) $(\lnot p\to \lnot q)\to (q\to p)$

(K axiom) $\square (p\to q) \to (\square p\to \square q)$

(Dual axioms) $\diamond p \to \lnot \square \lnot p$ , $\lnot \square \lnot p \to \diamond p$

(K4 axiom) $\diamond \diamond p\to \diamond p$

(S4 axiom) $p \to \diamond p$

(S5 axiom) $p\to \square \diamond p$

And the rules of inference are:

(MP) if $p$ and $p\to q$ both are true then $q$ is true

(N) if $p$ is true the $\square p $ is true

I know it is actually using these axioms efficiently but I can not make a good start and puzzled here. I am not finding a way to solve the problem.

I appologise for not showing a good effort from my end but I am completely stuck here.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thnx in advance.

Comment: Consider a Kripke model containing a world $w$ that satisfies $\Diamond \Box \phi$. Then some world $w'$ visible from $w$ satisfies $\Box \phi$. Thus every world visible from $w'$ satisfies $\phi$. But, because of S5, visibility is an equivalence relation. Thus, we have that every world visible from $w$ is visible from $w'$, and vice versa. Thus every world visible from $w$ satisfies $\phi$. Thus $w$ satisfies $\Box \phi$. We conclude every world $w$ satisfies $\Diamond \Box \phi \to \Box \phi$. Now, use the completeness proof for S5 to show $\Diamond \Box \phi \to \Box \phi$ is provable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for stating all those axioms!  Here's a sketch.

The $K4$ scheme gives

$$\vdash\square p\to \square\square p.$$

By $N$ and the $K$ scheme it follows that

$$\vdash\lozenge\square p\to \lozenge\square\square p.$$

But this together with the instance

$$\vdash \lozenge \square\square p\to \square p$$

of the $S5$ scheme gives the desired

$$\vdash \lozenge \square p\to \square p.$$

Incidentally, one strategy for finding axiomatic proofs (besides being a machine) is to start by giving a semantic argument like that in Carl's comment above.  This will give some sense of the shape of the proof, e.g., what axioms are needed.

Comment: Thnx for your answer. I can not understand how you concluded the third line ie $\diamond \square \square p \to \square p$. Perhaps I am missing something. Will you please help me to understand?Thnx again.

Comment: After choosing $\neg p$ for $p$, contraposing and taking duals, the $S5$ axiom gives you $\lozenge\square p\to p$.  The third line results from this by choosing $\square p$ for $p$.

Comment: I got it now. Thnx a lot.

Comment: Oh, a couple more comments.  (i) in my experience, it was helpful to separate the purely modal part of these derivation problems from the awkwardness of working in an axiomatic system of propositional logic; e.g., just use truth-functional consequence freely wherever you see it and worry about formalizing that stuff later.  (ii) $\diamond$ is `\diamond`, $\lozenge$ is `\lozenge`. (iii) that's a great book; stick with it!

Comment: Thnx a lot for your comment. Really helpful. I will try to do as much as from that book